# Why is uiview repositioned when application re-enters active state

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

I have an iOS application where the main screen that is launched (A login screen) has 3 text fields and a button to "Login" below the fields.  There is a content view within the main view which holds the fields and the button and it is vertically centered. When any of the 3 fields begins editing, the view shifts up such that they are visible and so is the button. The relevant code for this is:

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [userName addTarget: self action: @selector(slideFrameUp:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
    [userName addTarget: self action: @selector(slideFrameDown:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];

     //.... same thing for 2 other fields

}
-(void) slideFrameUp: (id)sender {
    CGFloat slidePoints = 116.0;
    [self slideFrame: YES distance: slidePoints];
}


-(void) slideFrameDown: (id)sender {
    CGFloat slidePoints = 116.0;
    [self slideFrame: NO distance: slidePoints];
}


-(void) slideFrame:(BOOL) up distance: (NSInteger)amount {
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed
    int movement = (up ? -amount : amount);
    [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This works fine and does what we need. The one hiccup is that when the user is editing a text field and presses the home button and then opens the app again, when the app re-opens (if it only went to background and wasn't killed) it will be positioned exactly how it was previously initially (for like 1/10th of a second) and then it will reset back to center with the keyboard still present, thus leaving it lower on the screen than it should be and hiding some fields. The thing is none of my code runs when the view position resets. slideFrame is not called at all either when the app enters background or when it goes back to active. None of my view related methods (viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear/viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear, etc) are called on entering background or active. I'm wondering why does ios reposition my view when going back to active, and how can I prevent it?

I figured out one solution which I didn't really like. What I did was observe UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification  and then dismiss the keyboard using the code:

```
[self.view endEditing: YES];
```

This seems to work fine except when the app opens the user is no longer focused in the field. I would prefer though if the app just opened back up as it was.  I'm also just kind of curious why the system behaves this way and if maybe there is a more elegant way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to dismiss the keyboard as the app goes to background and set focus on your text field in viewWillAppear:

Comment: viewWillAppear isn't called when the app transitions back to foreground.. The iOS system resets the view on its own. I think the best solution is detect if the keyboard is showing and if so slide up the screen again (when app becomes active, after a short timeout as otherwise the system hasn't repositioned my window yet).